# Plaque Wording and Capitalization

Tags: capitalization

When writing a message on a plaque using multiple lines to communicate the message, is it appropriate to capitalize the first word of each line, even if the line is a continuation of a sentence shown on the prior line?  Example:

> To Management and Staff of ABC Company,
>   For your valued partnership and
>   Creativity in development of new
>   Technology that will improve the
>   Lives of transplant patients all
>   Around the world, we express our
>   Deepest gratitude and appreciation,
>   On the occasion of ABC's 20th Anniversary.
>   Presented June 5, 2013, in Los Angeles California

Additional question:  Would "Anniversary" be capitalized since it is an event being recognized?  And, would there not be a comma between Los Angeles and California?
This is similar to wording I received from management to use on an appreciation plaque—I'd like to get it right, whether I'm right or they're right.

Answer (score 2):

I would very definitely NOT capitalise each line: it makes it harder to read and I know of no reason why this should be done.

I also would NOT capitalise "Anniversary" where it's used just as part of the sentence, even if that is what is being recognised. It *might* be acceptable to capitalise it in a heading / title, but not just in a sentence.

Yes, there should be a comma after Los Angeles.

Comment: I'd probably prefer "Twentieth Anniversary" (capitalizing both words).  If "20th" is written using digits, then "anniversary" should be lowercase, but I'd suggest that's because what's being recognized is not the fact that it's "an" anniversary (of which there will hopefully be dozens), but rather that it's the Twentieth, of which there will only ever be one.

Answer (score 1):

Capitalisation of each line, these days, is only used for exterior reasons (one of the commonest is an acrostic, where the capital letters spell out a word or phrase).  Here, it would give the wrong impression.

Capitalising *Anniversary* would be too solemn for usual language, but would not be wrong in a plaque.

And yes, if you want to include 'California' (to distinguish this Los Angeles from the others around the world), you need a comma.